# getting a not found 404 error while trying to post in node js application

Tags: node.js

I am trying to submit a registration form in a **`node.js`** application with all empty fields. Validation should redirect back to same page with errors. But an error page is appearing with `404` not found message. URL of the page is also misleading.

http://localhost:3000/users/users/register. I do not know why two times users appear.The `get` requests works fine. Only issue is with `post`.

This is my app.js code:

```
var express = require('express');
var expressValidator = require('express-Validator');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var passport = require('passport');
var localStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var multer = require('multer');
var upload = multer({ dest: './uploads' });
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var db = mongoose.connection;


var index = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(expressValidator({
  errorFormatter: function(param, msg, value) {
      var namespace = param.split('.')
      , root    = namespace.shift()
      , formParam = root;

    while(namespace.length) {
      formParam += '[' + namespace.shift() + ']';
    }
    return {
      param : formParam,
      msg   : msg,
      value : value
    };
  }
}));
//app.use(multer({dest:'./uploads'}));
// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use(session({
secret:'secret',
saveUnitialized:true,
resave:true
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());



app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(flash());
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.locals.messages = require('express-messages')(req, res);
  next();
});

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

here is my post code:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.post('/register', function(req, res, next) {


  var name = req.body.name;
  var email = req.body.email;
  var username = req.body.username;
  var password1 = req.body.password;
  var password = req.body.password2;

  req.checkBody('name','Name Field is required').notEmpty();
req.checkBody('email','Email Field is required').notEmpty();
req.checkBody('email','Email is incorrect format').isEmail();
req.checkBody('username','UserName is required').notEmpty();
req.checkBody('password','Password is required').notEmpty();
req.checkBody('password2','Password do not match').equals(req.body.password);

var errors = req.validationErrors();

if(errors){
    res.render('register',{
        errors:errors,
        name:name,
        email:email,
        username:username,
        password:password,
        password2:password2,

    });
}
    });
```

here is my register.jade code:

```
extends layout 

block content
    h1 Register
    p Please register using the form below
    ul.errors
        if errors
            each errors, i in errors
                li.alert.alert-danger #{error.msg}
    form(method='post',action='users/register')
        .form-group
            label Name
            input.form-control(name='name',type='text',placeholder='Enter Name')
        .form-group
            label Email
            input.form-control(name='email',type='email',placeholder='Enter Email')
        .form-group
            label UserName
            input.form-control(name='username',type='text',placeholder='Enter UserName')
        .form-group
            label Password
            input.form-control(name='password',type='password',placeholder='Enter Password')
        .form-group
            label Confirm Password
            input.form-control(name='password2',type='password',placeholder='Confirm Password')
        input.btn.btn-default(name='submit',type='submit',value='Register')
```

Comment: Where is your `app.js` code ?

Comment: i have added the app.js code

Comment: do u want the registration page or the code were i am writing my post code

Comment: I think it's equally important to show how (code and/or html) you are making the request.

Answer (score 0):

please uses the following link to access the page you are looking for

http://localhost:3000/users/register

on your layout.jade make sure your navigation links are as follows

```
ul.navbar-nav.navbar-right
          li.nav-item(class=(title == 'Members' ? 'active' : ''))
            a.nav-link(href='/') Members
          li.nav-item(class=(title == 'Register' ? 'active' : ''))
            a.nav-link(href='/users/register') Register
          li.nav-item(class=(title == 'Login' ? 'active' : ''))
            a.nav-link(href='/users/login') Login
        ul.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right
          li.nav-item
            a.nav-link(href='/users/logout') Logout
```